# iptables recent module --set option

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I read a firewall script including following lines

```
iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --update --seconds 60 -hitcount 600 -j DROP 

iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --set
```

This is a part of deny by default firewall script and pfc is a user-defined subchain of INPUT.

Isn't something wrong here? The second line doesn't jump to a chain. What is the fate of packet unless first line match?

I think it should be done

```
iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --set **-j ACCEPT**
```

Isn't that right?

Comment: Should it be a question for http://serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, this rule:

```
iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --set
```

Sets the `recent` entry for the packet, and then continues to process additional `iptables` rules that may decide to explicitly reject or accept the packet.

On the other hand, your suggested modification...

```
iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --set -j ACCEPT
```

...accepts the packet immediately with no further processing.  That's a substantial difference in behavior, and whether or not it's appropriate depends entirely on your local situation.

Comment: Larks i wonder this;

According to following line-->

#iptables -A pfc -p udp --dport 5060 -m recent --name badguy --set
The rule will be matched on the chain so i dont expect it to continue ?

What do you think?

Setting the recent entry is not a matching of the rule ?

Comment: I think I have accurately described the behavior of these rules. Absent an explicit `-j` option, a rule does not determine the disposition of a packet and processing continues at the next rule.  You may want to set up a simple firewall to test this behavior.

Comment: Converting to comment from answer: Larsks is correct and has given a great answer. As per the 'man iptables' page -

"If this option is omitted in a rule (and -g is not used), then matching the rule will have no effect on the packet's fate, but the counters on the rule will be incremented."

I tested this and it's indeed the case so it'll just match your default rule and be accepted/dropped/rejected accordingly.